# Phase lag of an ISO124 isolation amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, delay, phase

I want to use an ISO124 isolation amplifier. The input frequency will be about 100Hz. I'm trying to figure out what the phase delay will be from the input to the output and i'm not having any luck. I can't seem to find anything in the data sheet (or i just don't know where to look).

From the data sheet how can the phase delay of a 100Hz input signal be figured out?

[OPA124 data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso124.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

If you assume single pole 50kHz response (which is obviously not 100% accurate) the phase shift becomes simply:

\$\phi = -\tan^{-1}(100/50000) \approx -0.11°\$

It's not a linear system- it modulates and demodulates to cross the barrier- so 'phase shift' is only going to be an approximation anyhow. You can see significant artifacts and aliasing as you approach the modulation frequency.

There is doubtless some some small amount of 'dead time' in this kind of system (should be less than 1/fmod or 2usec nominally) so very small angles may not follow the approximation so well. But 0.11° is quite a bit more than that (about 30usec).

Comment: I see where it mentions that "Standard ISO124 has 50kHz single-pole (Butterworth) response." but this is for magnitude. How can it be inferred that the phase response would also be like a single pole Butterworth?